# django url fails with optional parameters

Tags: python, django, url

Below is my django routing configuration:

```
# main module
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
)

# api module
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.users, name='users')
)
```

I can access specific users (using ids) with `http://localhost:8000/api/users/1/` but I can't access list of users: `http://localhost:8000/api/users/`:

```
Using the URLconf defined in duck_rip.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^api/ ^$ [name='index']
^api/ ^users/(?P<id>\d+) [name='users']
The current URL, api/users/, didn't match any of these.
```

Before this, I had my module urls like this:

```
url(r'^users/$', views.users, name='users')
```

and I had access to `http://localhost:8000/api/users/`. Can someone please explain me what is the error I make?

Comment: The error is straight forward none of the url patterns is handling 
`^users/$`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary what should I change to make `id` parameter optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make id optional as:

```
url(r'^users/(?:(?P<id>\d+)/)?$', views.users, name='users')
```

And in view:

```
def users(request, id=None)
```